# How can we get the results of assertion in Slim/Fitnesse

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

We have a fitnesse / slim table where in the fourth instruction is my assertion for the test case.is there a way we can get the result of this particular method as Pass or Fail.
For example

```
!|Fixture|
|method1|method2|method3|**method4**|
|res    |res2   |res3   |**TCresult**|
```

For example here i want to know if method4 passed or failed.We have a different reporting system which cannot be done away with and every test case result needs to be validated.Also one test script have more that one test case in it.So we want the pass or fail of those methods which validate test cases.

Comment: Can you post your fixture code? It's hard to understand what's happening without seeing the code.

Comment: Not enough information in the question.  You've tagged it with "selenium-webdriver" so my guess might be you are trying to put fitnesse over the top of unit tests that utilize webdriver.  Which may be very challenging depending on how those tests are architected.

Answer (score -1):

script
given test page Testpage
and Test System setup is    !define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!path lib/*.jar
and Setup content is
!|import|
|fitnesse.slim.test|

!|Scenario|Stop Test|
|start|ConstructorThrows|stop test|

!|Scenario|Not Executed|MESSAGE |
|check|echo|@MESSAGE|cannot fail @MESSAGE|

and Test content is 
!|Script|
|Stop Test|
|Not Executed and should be ignored|
!|Script|
|Not Executed and should be ignored as well|
when page   Testpage    is tested and HTML is extracted
then    \d  assertions pass,    0   fail,   0   are ignored 1   exceptions thrown
and cell    Stop Test   has result  error
and cell    Not Executed and should be ignored  has result  ignore
and cell    Not Executed and should be ignored as well  has result  ignore
and cell    Test not run    has result  ignore
show Symbol $HTML_Input
show Symbol $HTML_Result
get collapsed executon log for page Testpage

Comment: Please use some formatting. The answer is illegible like this.